# I want to prevent tkinter .exe from starting multiple times

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I compile my Python tkinter code, when I run *.exe twice, there are two main tkinter windows (same as when I run windows notepad.exe twice).

But I want to prevent tkinter .exe from being able to start twice. What can I do so that tkinter can only be started once? Whether or not I click tkinter.exe on the windows desktop dozens of times.

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63525619/how-can-i-disable-multiple-instances-of-a-python-script) help at all?

Answer (score 1):

Requirements
`pip install wmi`

Suggested Solution

```py
if "tkinkter.exe" in [ x.Name for x in wmi.WMI().Win32_Process() ]:
   exit()
```

Source: [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-get-list-of-running-processes/#:~:text=Win32_Process%20function%20in%20order%20to,and%20stored%20in%20variable%20process](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-get-list-of-running-processes/#:%7E:text=Win32_Process%20function%20in%20order%20to,and%20stored%20in%20variable%20process).